# My query is not showing a result but if I single out the result I need in a sub select statement, it works as expected

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

```
select  * 
from data_syncs 
where id in (select  max(ds.id) 
             from data_syncs ds 
             where ds.institute_type = 'School' 
             group by ds.institute_id)
```

I'm looking for the result '946768' as an ID. Notice no results are shown:
[Screenshot of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGHzh.png)

However, if I change the query to the following:

```
select  * 
from data_syncs 
where id in (select  max(ds.id) 
             from data_syncs ds 
             where ds.institute_type = 'School' 
               and id=946768 
             group by ds.institute_id)
```

the result shows up as expected:
[limited query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuM84.png)

I know that the first statement contains '946768' as expected too:

```
select  max(ds.id) 
from data_syncs ds 
where ds.institute_type = 'School' 
group by ds.institute_id
```

[Original statement as a standalone query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjH5c.png)

Why does '946768' not show up in the first query, but does for the other 2?

Comment: Do you really need a subquery ? Wouldn't this be sufficient: `SELECT  * FROM data_syncs WHERE institute_type = 'School' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`